# How to allow only web app to access web service?

Tags: javascript, cors, soapui

I've got a webapp, which makes JavaScript call to web service. I don't want to let access any programs like SOAP ui/curl make post request to my web service.
In response header I make filtering to only my webpage:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://myurl.com
```

When I do the request from my local machine the server is not allowing to do so:

> **`XMLHttpRequest`:** cannot load *http://myurl.com/service/rest/user/add*. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header has a value *http://myurl.com* that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin *http://localhost:9000* is therefore not allowed access.

Which is good, I'm pretty happy but apparently I can use Soap ui/curl to make the above call  and the service allows it. Headers for this call:

```
=== MimeHeaders ===
accept-encoding = gzip,deflate
content-type = application/json
content-length = 39
host = localhost:8080
connection = Keep-Alive
user-agent = Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

How to allow only my web app origin to make calls to the service?

Comment: There's really no reliable way to enforce such a restriction. Why would you want to?

Comment: CORS is only enforced by a (supporting) client-side browser when it contacts a resource on a remote domain. Hence when a remote server or any other kind of remote software sends an HTTP request to your server, CORS is not applicable. Limiting access to the service depends among other factors on your setup and server type. Please share those too.

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin and similar headers are used by browsers, and since curl doesn't run in a browser those headers are ignored. You could try checking Referrer, or the agent string, use generated tokens etc, but you will not be able to 100% block anything that is not your app.

Answer (score 0):

CORS are only working for the browsers sandbox. If you want to prevent access put some auth like eg [basic auth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basic_access_authentication) or use some custom headers to whitelist calls.

Answer (score 0):

What you defined here is just a client-side protection to beware your browser clients from executing malicious requests against your server as long as the browser isn't run in an unsafe mode.

If you need security for your backend, consider restricting the network access using some kind of firewall or secure your backend with an authentication mechanism like Basic Auth.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: You can't be sure 100% that the Javascript in your webpage make the request. By definition, that's your users that making the requests.

Other answer: You can use multiple stuff to protect yourself.

1. Generating a cookie with limited lifetime.
2. Make a throttle so you can limit the number of requests by time unit.
3. ....

There are many more other solutions, just search for it on the web, you'll find plenty.